# How to set GET_APP_OPS_STATS without rooting?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-app-ops

i am working on an app using the App Ops Manager. I want to get access to the Logs and analyze which app used which resource. The app works fine for the moment, since a wanted to deplay a Demo version. I have the following problem:

I started the App from Android Studio all the time and granted the Permission "GET_APP_OPS_STATS" manually by using adb.exe. Now ive wrote it down in the AndroidManifest.xml by simply using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_APP_OPS_STATS" />
```

This permission doesnt work in the app and I dont get asked to set it manually (like the one for accessing the storage). I think this could be caused by the permission itself, which could be a system permission.

Are there any solutions, how i can use the App Ops Logs without rooting my device od using third party software? Maybe there is another permission i have to set or some code that sets /asks for the permission.

Best regards,
Marvin

Comment: "which could be a system permission" -- correct (or, more accurately, its `protectionLevel` is `signature|privileged|development`). "how i can use the App Ops Logs without rooting my device" -- create your own custom ROM, with your app pre-installed, and with the app signed by the same signing key that signed the ROM.

Comment: Ive should have said, we cannot use a custom rom. It must be an app able to be installed on every android device.

Comment: Then I sincerely hope that this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Well, thats exactly the reason for this app. We want to grab the log data, analyse them and show the user which app did what on the phone. We wanna compare these log data with other data like wether the app was on or off and things like that